# How to change my struct pointer to a new struct, and free the old struct

Tags: c

I've pinpointed a bug in this function at the last three lines, which are meant to point `ht` to `newHash` and then call `deleteMap` on the old `hashMap` struct that `ht` used to point to.

```
void _setTableSize(struct hashMap * ht, int newTableSize)
{
    struct hashMap *newHash;
    newHash = createMap(newTableSize);
    struct hashLink * temp;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < ht->tableSize; i++){
        temp = ht->table[i];
        while (temp != 0){
            insertMap(newHash, temp->key, temp->value);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    struct hashMap *temp2 = ht;
    ht = newHash;
    deleteMap(temp2);

}
```

I know this must be wrong, because `ht` seems to point to garbage after I do this, but I can't figure out how to do it properly.

Comment: Your assignment to `ht` has no effect on the `ht` known to the caller. Either put an additional indirection level (meh) or have the function return the "new" `ht` to the caller (and have it use that new instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning a value to `ht`, however because it is a parameter to the function (and all parameters are pass-by-value), this value is not reflected when the function returns.

If you want to modify `ht` so that the caller sees the changes, you either need to pass the address of the pointer and change the function to accept a `struct hashMap **ht`, or have the function return a `struct hashMap *`.